# Binomial distribution tail inequality

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ does there exist $l$ ideally $l=f(n)$ such that $P(X<l)=o(1)$ in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$? I'd be looking for the largest possible $l$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want this as a function of $p$ as well, *and* that $p$ is a constant in $(0,1)$? (if $p=p_n$ or $p=0$, then it'll be tricky or hopeless).

You can use generalize the following fact (here for $p=1/2$) with the appropriate constants:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{ X \in \left[\frac{n}{2} - c\sqrt{n}, \frac{n}{2}+c\sqrt{n} \right]\right\} \in (1\pm o(1))\cdot[e^{-2c^2},1]\cdot 2c\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} = \Theta(c)
$$
The bound is loose for "big" $c$'s, but you can adapt the argument (which is basically using Chernoff-type bounds/Stirling's approximation) to argue that the $\ell$ you are looking for will be of the form $pn - f(n,p)\sqrt{n}$, where the dependence of $f(n,p)$ is mild (e.g., logarithmic).

Comment: yes sorry I wanted it to be a function of $p$ also but $p=p(n)$ and is not constant.

Comment: Then the same approach will work -- but it'll be messier.